# Error "The method withDefaultPasswordEncoder() is undefined for the type User" Spring Boot password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to include a username and password into my spring application. I was reading the spring docs and it said to put in the below code to implement this. I am getting the following errors 
(** The method withDefaultPasswordEncoder() is undefined for the type User) on the UserDetails Service**.)

I have looked at the docs and tried some other forums to try and solve this but I can't find anything that works.
Please see the image below for the errors as well as the pom.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks in advance!!!

[image: Code inside my Security package]
[image: Pom File]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your method userDetailsService. You need to override method from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {..}
```

For example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user1")
        .password("password1")
        .roles("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .withUser("user2")
        .password("password1")
        .roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
}
```

}

You can check my repo: https://github.com/dmcheremisin/SpringBootSecurity/tree/master/basic.security

Additionally, good article(similar to my code): https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security

Comment: That works man thanks!!!! Will I just change the ant matchers to the urls I want to the user to have to enter thier password?

Comment: You can mark my answer as answer =) 
You need to provide for each ant matcher roles that applicable for ant matcher's url. 
If you want to restrict access to all urls, than use: antMatcher("/**"). This pattern "/**" is applicable to any url of the application at any level. 
In your example - you have user with name "user" and role -> "USER".

Comment: One more thing, sorry. To Log out do i have to pout in anything special?

Comment: Yes, by default /logout request should be POST method. And you should provide csrf token or disable them by using http.csrf().disable()